# Calculations and rounding in R

Tags: r, rounding

Why this example will return 0.93

```
> trunc(0.94/100*100*100)/100
[1] 0.93
```

but this example:

```
> trunc(0.94*100)/100
[1] 0.94
```

returns 0.94. It is floating point error. How can I transform result of the calculations `0.94/100*100*100` in normal 94?

Comment: This is due to floating point error.  Look at the result of `0.94/100*100*100 - 94`.  So while R prints `94`, the number is stored as something ever so slightly less than `94`. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: how can I transform 0.94/100*100*100 in normal 94?

Comment: wrap it in `integer`!

Comment: trunc(as.integer(0.94/100*100*100))/100   not work

Answer (score 1):

As Justin said in the comments, floating point error.

Read this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

(it applies to statisticians and scientists too, at least one who use computers!)